# Removing eslint error 'Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ; (Fatal)' in react native code

Tags: react-native, eslint

I am doing some code in react-native and getting this error 
"Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";" (Fatal)" in my code

index.js

```
export const emailChanged = (text) => {
  rerutn {              ///getting error at this line//
  type: EMAIL_CHANGED,
  payload: text
  };
  };
```

.eslintrc

```
 {
"extends": "rallycoding",
 "rules": {
  "arrow-body-style": 1
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to be `return` instead of `rerutn`. So your code would look like this:

```
export const emailChanged = (text) => {
  return {
    type: EMAIL_CHANGED,
    payload: text
  };
};
```